# Cannot connect to EC2 PostgreSQL database from ASP.Net Core lambda function

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and my question is regarding connection to Postgresql database hosted as a EC2 instance in AWS.

I have an Asp.net core web api published as a AWS Serverless Application and an endpoint which connects to the mentioned DB. When running the api on localhost or connecting to DB from any DB client everything is ok but it does not work when testing on AWS. I assume it is connected to security configurations of EC2 but don't know how to figure it out.

Here's the serverless.template code

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Transform" : "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description" : "Starting template for an AWS Serverless Application.",
  "Parameters" : {
  },
  "Resources" : {
    "DefaultFunction" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "AwsApp.WebApi::AwsApp.WebApi.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "Description": "Default function",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaFullAccess" ],
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs" : {
    "ApiURL" : {
        "Description" : "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
        "Value" : { "Fn::Sub" : "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/" }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the error message

```
An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ResultEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinder`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at AwsApp.WebApi.Controllers.ValuesController.Get(Int32 id) in D:\TEST\.NET Core\AwsApp\AwsApp.WebApi\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 33
```

Also it is strange why there's a path to the file within the error message

**Edit**

PostgreSQL is running under VPC.
There's a dummy Get method in controller which returns a simple array:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
   return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

When I set my lambda function VPC then this function also fails with error 500.

**Solution**

I was able to fix it.
The role assigned to my lambda function didn't have required policies (see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/demystifying-lambda-in-vpc-and-its-confusing-error)).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John,

There can be multiple issues....

1. If your PostgreSQL is running inside a VPC with private subnet configured, open the port in firewall (inbound traffic) so that your lambda can connect.
2. You need to create a new role with permission to PostgreSQL and assign it to the Lambda.

Please try and post your comments.